# Android App (Kotlin) crashs without stack trace, Fatal singal 6

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I am currrently using Android Studio 4.1 Canary 10. The project I am working in is a Kotlin Multiplatform Project, with the following building blocks.

The base is a gradle-Project, where all the multiplatform stuff is happening. The most important parts here is the business layer, which uses Ktor and SQLDelight for Rest and Persistence.

This base is used in an Android Library atop of it, which contains template resources to be overwritten by the actual Android App. The background is, that we want to develop an App which can easily be rebranded for different customers.

The setup as it is works fine, most of the time. When running the app via adb on a physical test device (most of them are samsung), the app seems to be stable. When running it on an AVD tho, I randomly get crashes without a stack trace or any full java error. The only message I get is this:

```
2020-06-10 12:02:31.127 6562-6650/xxx.xxxx.xx.xxxxx A/libc: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -1 (SI_QUEUE) in tid 6650 (Studio:Heartbea), pid 6562 (ulso.xxx.xxxx)
```

NOTE: I removed the package name and replaced it with x

Those crashes appear since using Canary 10 of AS. Could have todo something with this Version, althoug I could not find anything with this error message in my google search, therefore I wanted to ask if anybody else faces the same problem, and if there is any solution to this?

Thanks in advance!